# how to send DIV content to html5 CANVAS

Tags: jquery, css, html, canvas

Is it possible to "draw" the content of a div to a canvas... i have done the div manipulation with css, but need canvas to "save" the content to jpg with the .dataToURL function

so the question is... do you know a HTML, CSS, jQuery function that transfer the content of a div and draw it to a canvas

thanks in advance

Comment: Something like https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas ?

Comment: silly me i google div2canvas !... will check it out

Comment: The script is still in a very experimental state, so I don't recommend using it in a production environment nor start building applications with it yet, as there will be still major changes made. However, please do test it out and report your findings, especially if something should be working, but is displaying it incorrectly.

Comment: Have you checked http://www.williammalone.com/articles/create-html5-canvas-javascript-drawing-app/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<canvas>` does not directly support placing HTML content on it, as combining this with `<IFRAME>` could potentially lead to lost of private information.

What you can do is that you dynamically create SVG image and then draw this on `<canvas>`. SVG has better support for rich-text formatting than `<canvas>`.

jQuery library for dynamic SVG creation:

http://keith-wood.name/svg.html

(See Text example)

Answer (score 1):

Check out html2Canvas, it takes a dom element and converts it to a canvas, and then you can draw that canvas onto another canvas something like this:

http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/

```
var domElement = document.getElementById('myElementId');
html2canvas(domElement, {
    onrendered: function (domElementCanvas) {
        var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(domElementCanvas, 0, 0, 100, 100);

        // do something with canvas
    }
}
```